# Rounded CSS triangle upside down

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I found a code for creating a rounded triangle shape. I would like to rotate the whole triangle upside down to resemble the triangle-shaped mark that is usually used in dropdown-select elements.

```css
.triangle {
 position: relative;
 background-color: orange;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}
.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 /*width:  7px;
 height: 7px;*/
  width:  30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.triangle {
 transform: rotate(-60deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.triangle:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.triangle:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}


/* styles below for demonstration purposes only */
body { padding: 30px; }
.triangle:hover { background: red; }
.triangle:hover:before { background: blue; }
.triangle:hover:after { background: green; }
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Also, here is CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdNKzX?editors=1100

The triangle in the code I found is made up by connecting 3 smaller pieces that represents different states of the same `.triangle` element (`:hover`, `:after` and default).

`.triangle`, `.triangle:before` and `.triangle:after` are formed into desired shape by using `transform` property, that is a combination of `rotate()`, `skew()`, `scale()` and `translate()` functions.

The problem is I am not familiar with the usage of those functions. In fact I think the shape-forming process was done using some paid CSS generator, because I can't imagine anyone to know exactly what values should be inserted into those functions not by trial and error.

Comment: Just remove the `rotate(-60deg)` from the `.triangle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the style class .triangle

```
.triangle {
    transform: skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
```

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}

.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  /*width:  7px;
 height: 7px;*/
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.triangle {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) scale(1, .866);
}

.triangle:before {
  transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414, .707) translate(0, -50%);
}

.triangle:after {
  transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707, 1.414) translate(50%);
}


/* styles below for demonstration purposes only */

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.triangle:hover {
  background: red;
}

.triangle:hover:before {
  background: blue;
}

.triangle:hover:after {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: `rotate(0deg)`... huh? XD

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol is absolutely right, you may remove the rotate :-)

Comment: @Kloker It is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

By removing rotate attribute in the triangle class

```
 .triangle {
        transform: skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
    }
```

Try out the snippet below

```css
.triangle {
 position: relative;
 background-color: orange;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}
.triangle,
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
 /*width:  7px;
 height: 7px;*/
  width:  30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-top-right-radius: 30%;
}

.triangle {
 transform: skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}
.triangle:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}
.triangle:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}


/* styles below for demonstration purposes only */
body { padding: 30px; }
.triangle:hover { background: red; }
.triangle:hover:before { background: blue; }
.triangle:hover:after { background: green; }
```

```html
<div class='triangle'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `120deg` instead of `-60px`. Means you want to rotate 180deg. -60 + 180 = 120.

```
transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
```

Comment: Rotating an equilateral triangle by 120 degrees is a no-op.